# Mysql node module is not installing

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

I have been trying to install mysql module for node.js in my Linux 17.10 using the following command:

```
npm install -g mysql
```

However, this error below keeps on coming though I tried a lot to remove.

> `divyanshu@DVProBook:~/Documents/nodejsassignment$ npm install -g mysql`
>
> `npm ERR! Linux 4.13.0-38-generic`
>
> `npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "mysql"`
>
> `npm ERR! node v6.11.4`
>
> `npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2`
>
> `npm ERR! code ECONNRESET`
>
> `npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT 172.16.19.10:80`
>
> `npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself`
>
> `npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.`
>
> `npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.`
>
> `npm ERR! network`
>
> `npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>   npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'`
>
> `npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:`
>
> `npm ERR! /home/divyanshu/Documents/nodejsassignment/npm-debug.log`

I tried changing my connection but didn't help.

If anyone knows whats wrong then please help. Thank you

Comment: You have `node v6.11.4`, yet the latest version is either 8 or 9. Install version 8 and retry. Also, post the log file in your question.

Comment: Thank you for replying but i got the solution. I just needed to change the https in npm help config to http .